# Why does XML::LibXML keeps printing errors even when I disable them?

Tags: html, perl, libxml2, xml-parsing

I'm using `XML::LibXML` to parse a document.

The HTML file behind it, has some minor errors, and the parser reports them:

```
http://is.gd/create.php?longurl=http://google.com:15: validity error : ID smallink already defined
nal URL was <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a><span id="smallink"
                                                                                ^
http://is.gd/create.php?longurl=http://google.com:15: validity error : ID smallink already defined
and use <a href="http://is.gd/fNqtL-">http://is.gd/fNqtL-</a><span id="smallink"
                                                                                ^
```

However, I disabled error reporting:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser->set_options({ recover           => 2,
                       validation        => 0,
                       suppress_errors   => 1,
                       suppress_warnings => 1,
                       pedantic_parser   => 0,
                       load_ext_dtd      => 0, });

my $doc = $parser->parse_html_file("http://is.gd/create.php?longurl=$url");
```

My only option to suppress those errors, is to run the script with `2>/dev/null`, which I don't want. Could someone help me please get rid of those errors?

Comment: If you think you have discovered a bug with Lib::LibXML, please report it to the author with a simple example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to install a `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler which filters the messages or just silences all warnings:

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { /* $_[0] is the message */ };
```

Comment: No need for a BEGIN block for this use, as far as I can see. local might be a good idea, though.

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea if you're asking XML::LibXML corretly to not print its warnings. I'll assume you are and this is a bug in XML::LibXML (which you should also report to the author), and only address how to suppress warnings.

Every time a warning is about to be printed, perl will look up the value of `$SIG{__WARN__}` and, if that contains a code reference, invoke it instead of printing the warning itself.

You can use that stop the warnings you want to ignore to be printed to `STDERR`. However, you should be careful with this. Make sure to only suppress false-positives, not *all* warnings. Warnings are usually useful. Also, make sure to localize your use of `$SIG{__WARN__}` to the smallest possible scope to avoid odd side effects.

```
# warnings happen just as always
my $parser = ...;
$parser->set_options(...);

{ # in this scope we filter some warnings
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        my ($warning) = @_;
        print STDERR $warning if $warning !~ /validity error/;
    };

    $parser->parse_html_file(...);
}

# more code, now the warnings are back to normal again
```

Also note that this is all assuming those warnings come from perl-space. It's quite possible that libxml2, the C library XML::LibXML uses under the hood, writes warnings directly to stderr itself. `$SIG{__WARN__}` will not be able to prevent it from doing that.